# SQL Server 2000 : want to use single stored procedure to return different types of SQL queries

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I've limitation to work on SQL Server 2000 on a very big project. For one module I've to create 3 to 10 stored procedures. To make it manageable I'm writing one stored procedure to return different SQL queries based on condition like:

```
If @QueryId = 'SelAllEmp'
   Select EmpId,EmpName from EMP 
ELSE IF  @QueryId = 'SelEmpById'
   Select EmpId,EmpName from EMP where EmpId= @EmpId
ELSE IF @QueryId = 'EMPDept'
   Select EmpId, DeptId, DeptName from EMPDept
......................................
```

My question is, are there any hidden consequences or impacts using this technique?

Comment: by making a single stored procedure that does different things, you'll be actually making it less manageable, harder to maintain and figure out in the future, I'd look at other ways of simplifying that elsewhere in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the way you are approaching this is manageable at all. For the cases you've shown in the question, you should strive to make that a single query. Let the *client* decide whether or not they'll use the `DeptName` column - the client has the option to ignore it, and knows to do so because it had to pass the `EmpDept` argument. If your client can ignore that column, then your three queries can become one:

```
SELECT EmpId, EmpName, DeptName
  FROM dbo.EMP 
  WHERE EmpId = CASE 
    WHEN @QueryId = 'SelEmpById' THEN @EmpId ELSE EmpId END;
```

This query solves all three of your conditions. To avoid getting stuck with a bad plan, you can add <strike>`OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the statement</strike> `WITH RECOMPILE` to the procedure. Yes this can cause overhead (not as bad as Joon makes it sound), but I'll take a little compilation every time over getting sucked into a horrible plan every other day. By default, SQL Server 2000 can't optimize all of your paths for a single stored procedure.

Another option is to build the query you need with dynamic SQL. This can cause plan cache bloat, but it shouldn't be too bad if all of the options are used frequently. <strike>You can avoid the problems this can cause for plan cache bloat by using the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` server setting.</strike>

Two very valuable reads by Erland Sommarskog:

- [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL (Version for SQL 2005 and Earlier)](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)
- [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Basically, don't be afraid of dynamic SQL, but be aware of the potential issues.

*Sorry, came back and edited since my answer was geared toward newer versions of SQL Server. It's hard to remember that people out there are still using SQL Server 2000 for some reason.*

Comment: It'll work, but as Aaron says, it won't be *manageable*. Think of it as "quick to write, expensive to use/maintain over time".

Answer (score 0):

When a stored proc gets above a certain complexity, it will recompile whenever it is called from the client.

This places overhead on the server, and in busy apps can cause overall performance degradation if it happens enough.

That is one potential negative consequence of following this technique.

Also, your result set changes based on the input to your stored proc. That will potentially break clients that expect a certain field to be present or not.